# Recognize task type by execution-id in Activiti

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

Is it possible to recognize the (BPMN) task type (service task, send task, receive task, ...) by execution-id in Activiti? How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With only that information you can not get what you want. Task types are about activities and activity ids. You can use `execution.getCurrentActivityId()` to retrieve activity id of execution. That can be helpful for you:

```
final Execution execution = runtimeService.createExecutionQuery().executionId(executionId).singleResult();
final ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceId(execution.getProcessInstanceId()).singleResult();
final BpmnModel bpmnModel = repositoryService.getBpmnModel(processInstance.getProcessDefinitionId());
final org.activiti.bpmn.model.FlowElement flowElement = bpmnModel.getFlowElement(((DelegateExecution) execution).getCurrentActivityId());
```

`flowElement` will be the activity you are looking for. You can check the type of it.

Comment: How I can get the task(delegateTask) Object here? I have no idea of activiti/BPMN